# IOS Simulator doesn't connect to VS Code

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, ios-simulator, vscode-extensions

I made my app on a windows machine. Now, I am trying to run the app on my Macbook Pro 14. when I select IOS Simulator from devices it starts to boot and VS Code waits for it to connect but it never connects even when the simulator has loaded. When I try to run it after that, a new instance of the simulator appears in the taskbar. which sits idle.
Also, Dart Dev Tools don't load I think. I'll link the important things below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The console show that you are using flutter 3.0.3 but the Dart sdk path is somewhere inside a Flutter 2.0.6 folder. How did you install Dart & Flutter (with Terminal or you downloaded the Flutter package and set the path yourself) ?

Comment: I installed a while back. I think i download the SDK and set the path myself. but i doubt the problem i am having is related to Dart. app runs on emulator fine. I think its to do with my scode version may be?

Comment: I suggest you to update or reinstall(the latest version) xcode and correct Dart sdk path.